# Setting up an external encrypted drive: "device does not exist"

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, encryption, luks

I am pretty new to linux and I am trying to install it on an external SSD (860 EVO connected via SATA to USC B adapter). I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvYM6hqTkQo) tutorial and having some troubles.

At first, I was able to get all the way through to the part where you select your region/time-zone and I got an error message saying one of my partitions couldn't be formatted. I looked into this and tried to manually format it and it gave me a "device in use" error or something like that.

I couldn't figure out why this was happing, but restarting my computer seemed to fix it. I was then able to get through the installation and tried the mounting steps. This got me to a "device does not exist" error, so I kept looking for other options. I eventually came to [this](https://linux-blog.anracom.com/2018/11/08/cryptsetup-close-not-working-for-lvm-on-luks-device-busy/) article and ran the `vgchange` and `cryptsetup close` commands and was able to get through the installation without needing to reboot first. This ultimately lead me back to the same spot: "device does not exist."

I tried `cryptsetup open` again but got "not a valid LUKS device." I scoured the internet for a solution and found a couple of articles talking about both problems I was encountering, but nothing would fix my situation.

I have spent too many hours already trying to get this to work, so any advice or help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why the user in the video you posted is issuing console ommands to do this setup + encryption manually. A modern Linux Distro like Ubuntu or Debian 10, I guess Fedora, Mint, etc, will all offer this in the setup of the installation as soon as you enter the partioning of disks part. There you can choose "Something else" or "Edit manually", to setup the partitions with e.g. full disk encryption. For exmaple see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577379/how-can-i-install-debian-with-full-disk-encryption-and-a-custom-sized-swapfile